# How to use single item from SCSS map or list?

Tags: css, sass, less

I have a list below:

```
$reboot: (
    'color': #000,
    'font-size': 16px,
    'font-weight': 400,
    'font-family': -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',.........etc,
);
```

Now, I want to use the `color` only like this way `$reboot.color/ $reboot['color']` or any others way, Here I don't need the loop. I need some specific items in different place.

Is it possible to use single items from a list (without loop)?

Answer (score 5):

This structure is a map. SASS provides a `get` function to access values for a particular key in the map.

You can do

```
map.get($reboot, 'color');
```

to just get a value.

You can get more info about it [in the official docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps)

**Updated Answer**

Other issue you are facing compiling the SASS code relates to the `font-family` assignment inside your map. Basically, you are providing a comma seperated value as the value for the `font-family` key.

```
$reboot: (
  'font-family': -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI'
);
```

Here, as soon as the SASS compiler reads the first comma after `-apple-system` it treats it as the end of the value and starts expecting the following statement to be another key-value pair. Hence, throwing compilation error.

You can define such comma-seperated values to another variable and then use it as a value inside the map

```
$family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI';
$reboot: (
   'color': #000,
   'font-size': 16px,
   'font-weight': 400,
   'font-family': $family
 );
```

Depending upon the version of your SASS you can choose to use either `map.get` or `map-get`

```
body{
  font-family: map-get($reboot, "font-family");
  background: map-get($reboot, "color");
 }
```

Comment: but it generates an error:  Invalid CSS after "...ont-family: map": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".get($reboot, 'font"

Comment: I think you should check your code again, you can do it with ```map.get( $list, 'item-name')``` and ```map-get($list, 'item-name')```